# How do we wrap user_url and display_name with href?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, href

How do we wrap `user_url` and `display_name` with href and make `display_name` the title, and `user_url` the url?

```
$idtag = '1234';

$user = get_user_by( 'id', $idtag );
echo 'Hello <a href="$user->user_url">' . $user->user_display_name . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
 echo 'Hello <a href="' .$user->user_url .'">' . $user->user_display_name . '</a>';
```

Or in html you can use it like this

`Hello <a href="<?= $user->user_url;?>"><?= $user->user_display_name;?></a>`